# jMeter source address not working

Tags: windows, jmeter

When source address field is empty, all runs fine. When I put in an IP, even if it is my actual IP, I get an error:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Network is unreachable: connect
```

I run Windows... Also I have already tried all the Implementations.

Comment: It only works if you set "Implementation" to "Java". 
Do you get the same error if you set address to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @KirilS. Thanks, please add an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking yesterday. I gave you WRONG answer. Unaccept it and I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

There should be few pre-requisites met:

- You need to have HTTPClient implementation (see [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler documentation)

  > Source address field[Only for HTTP Request with **HTTPClient** implementation]
- In case of single IP address:

  - The IP address needs to be available in the underlying operating system, it may be either IP associated with NIC or an [IP alias](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNKWF_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.doc/topics/tconfigip_win.html)
  - Relevant `Source address type` needs to be specified, in case of single IP it should be `IP/Hostname`

See [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) guide for more detailed information on the domain.

Comment: Yes, I have HTTP Request with HTTPClient implementation and the IP is available in the underlying operating system and is working in the browser. The Error is still there.